# Is there a specific spring component solely for loading properties/config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a specific Spring "starter" or maven coordinates which solely includes the functionality for defining config/properties files and also reading them into rich objects in your app?

I would like the convenience of being able to read in and define my properties file as if it was in a Spring Boot application, but it actualy being a vanilla Java app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring-context module can be used, it provides the functionality for handling application contexts and property sources. You could try it the following way.

1. You will need to add `spring-context` and `spring-context-support`in your pom.xml.
2. Create a configuration class like the following to read properties from properties file

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PropertiesConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties")); 
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

3. In your main Java application class, create an instance of AnnotationConfigApplicationContext to load the configuration

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(PropertiesConfig.class); //mention your configuration class name.
```

This should be able to read properties from your properties file. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks this was useful for me to build on and get a working solution to easily get the variable from the environment